# Error from web3.eth.getPastLogs() hex string without 0x prefix

Tags: web3js, error

I want to retrieve all token transfers to a given address by scanning the logs but receive an error. Am I doing something wrong? Could it be a web3 beta issue?

**Code**:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545"));
const transfer = web3.utils.keccak256( "Transfer(address,address,uint256)" );

// find all tokens received by this address ...
let sca = web3.utils.padLeft('0xEA674fdDe714fd979de3EdF0F56AA9716B898ec8', 64);

console.log( 'transfer: ', transfer );
console.log( '     sca: ', sca );

web3.eth.getPastLogs( {
    fromBlock: 1,
    toBlock: 'latest',
    topics: [transfer, null, sca, null]
  }
).then( (events) => { console.log( events ); } );
```

**Result**:

```
transfer:  0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef
     sca:  0x000000000000000000000000EA674fdDe714fd979de3EdF0F56AA9716B898ec8

Unhandled rejection Error: Returned error: invalid argument 0: hex string without 0x prefix
    at Object.ErrorResponse (/home/acct/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/src/errors.js:29:16)
    at /home/acct/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/src/index.js:137:36
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/home/acct/node_modules/web3-providers-http/src/index.js:64:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/home/acct/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/home/acct/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/home/acct/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:12)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/acct/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:469:24)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:975:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

**Environment**:

- node.js 7.8.0
- web3 1.0.0-beta.22
- geth 1.7.3-stable on go1.9
- Ubuntu x86_64

**Already tried**:

- use `WebsocketProvider` instead of `HttpProvider`
- specify `address: "0x..."` in the filter with a real address
- replace `fromBlock: 1` with `fromBlock: "0x1", and same using 0
- replace `null` topics with valid values
- forcing transfer and sca to be strings using for example sca = '' + web3...

**Yet to try**:

- revert to web3.js version 0.19

Comment: Your code works fine for me as-is against `ganache` and works with `fromBlock: "0x1"` when running against Infura (`https://mainnet.infura.io/<my-api-key>`). I'm using the current web3.js beta (1.0.0-beta.29).

Comment: To add: I upgraded my web3 to 1.0.0-beta.29 but I get the same error

Comment: So you're finding that it works with `testrpc` but not with `geth`?

Comment: The code works for me (with `fromBlock: "0x1"`) with geth. I'm on geth 1.7.3-stable with go1.9.4 on OS X.

Comment: I changed to `fromBlock: "0x1"` and it works now. So it was web3.js upgrade to beta 29 and this syntax change that did the trick !

Answer (score 2):

I have figured it out at my end while facing the same problem.
When you are using `fromBlock` and `toBlock` parameters in the function call `web3.eth.getPastLogs` you will have to cast the values to their hex version/equivalent.
Which can be done using :

```
web3.utils.toHex(<fromBlock/toBlock_Value>)
```

This worked for me.